# Visual Studio Intellisense bug or feature?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I don't know it's a bug or feature in Visual Studio but I found atleast on my VS 2010 that if I have a class say:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have `List<Person>` and I want to do collection initialization like below:

```
public static List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>
{
  new 
};
```

As you see it does not come up with `Person` object initializer, even if I press <kbd>ctrl + space</kbd>, it doesn't come up.

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Comment: Report it, maybe it will get added to 2012.

Comment: Resharper does this; it even offers derived types of Person, if any exist.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's more of a shortcoming than a bug.  It does not work in 2012 RC either.

[Here's the link to submit a suggestion:](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio)